# Replacement freehub

Tags: freehub

I am wanting to replace my existing free-hub, it came with the Giant SL1 disc centre lock wheel I bought and I assume it is a Shimano.

I am running Tiagra gears and a 10 speed cassette.

Can i just replace it with any 10 speed Shimano free-hub or is there compatibility issues?

Comment: Do you have the model year of the wheel? I suspect this is the 2017 version, but it would be useful to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

To chose the appropriate free-hub, there are two aspects to keep in mind.

- First, you need to be able to mount the free hub on the hub. Not all free hubs can be interchanged with each other, so you won't be ale to replace it with any random free hub. In order to chose a correct free hub, you need to check if it's compatible with the Giant Alloy centerlock disc hub.
- Second, you need to make sure that the free hub you select is a Shimano 10 (or 11) speed compatible one. As for example Campagnolo has a different layout of the "exterior" of the free hub, you won't be able to mount a Shimano 10 speed cassette on a Campagnolo compatible free hub.

**Update**: If you have a Gaint bike and the wheels are the stock version, you're likely to find the proper part number on [www.giantbikespares.com](http://www.giantbikespares.com/parts_lists).

Don't be afraid to use a Shimano 11 speed free hub. An 11 speed free hub would require a small spacer to compensate the slightly narrower 10 speed cassette but this works without any problem. In fact, Mavic shipped their wheels already with this kind of free hubs years before the 11 speed drive trains hit the market.

Answer (score 0):

It may (or may not work), but probably will not.

Freehub body internals and engagement mechanisms vary from manufacturer to manufacturer and even between models among the same manufacturer.

Some googling finds that those hubs are branded by Giant (https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/sl-1-alloy-centerlock-disc-road).  So, final answer is that they are not Shimano branded hubs and it's unlikely a Shimano freehub body will work on them.